# Marketing Definitions are not returned in CD instance from both Tracker and Marketing Definition Manager in Sitecore context

Tags: experience-analytics, content-delivery, marketing-definitions

I have tried to retrieve newly created definitions such as Goals, Outcomes, Profiles using

```
Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.Outcomes[newdefnitionid]
Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.Goals[newdefnitionid].
```

But it returns a null value and when I debug definitions available in the list

```
Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.Outcomes
Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.Goals
```

It only returns default Marketing definitions, not has new custom definitions. I already checked with the deployment status of marketing definitions from CM and reference databases. Those are deployed in CM and available in the ref database.

I have also tried with Marketing Definition Manager using the following code, it also does not return any definitions both default as custom.

```
private static IDefinitionManager<IOutcomeDefinition> OutcomeDefinitionManager
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetDefinitionManagerFactory().GetDefinitionManager<IOutcomeDefinition>();
            }
        }

 var outcomeDefinition = OutcomeDefinitionManager.Get(outComeDefinitionId, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   if (outcomeDefinition == null)
       {
           Log.Warn($"Cannot find outcome from marketing definitions manager: {outComeDefinitionId}", this);
           return false;
       }
```

The custom outcomes, goal definitions are getting added to the contact profile which I can see in the XP profile which confirms SAVE part is working with contact.

But READ part using Tracker, Definition Manager is not working from CD, ONLY after that works, we can able to register conversions from the page and the same conversions can be viewed in SA.

Comment: When you say you have "deployed in CM" have you checked they are in the 'web' database? CD typically is configured to load from the web database and does not have access to the master db, so that could be an issue.

Comment: it is deployed from CM. I verified , it is published to web database. In marketing definitions , we say it as deployed.